# Is it possible to convert mp4 files without ffmpeg?

Tags: php, video

I'm on a shared hosting account and I can't have the FFMPEG, FLVtool2 and MP4Box installed. Is there a workaround to convert mp4 files without these modules?

Comment: What *can* you run on your host? Because you don't want to be reimplementing ffmpeg in PHP... :o)

Comment: This is my first time working with videos so I have no idea what other modules there are that I can use...

Comment: Sure, you could write your own mp4 parser and codec system. Good luck... If the host won't let you install stuff (or install it for you), you're probably stuck.

Comment: Well, can you execute anything on that host? Put executables into a directory and run them? Or are you 100% restricted to what your host has preinstalled?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I guess my only solution is buying a VPS. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PHP extension that encapsulates ffmpeg. It's called [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/). It's a long shot, but maybe if you ask your hosting company nicely they can compile it and install it for you?

If not, you may want to consider switching to VPS hosting, then you can do pretty much whatever you want with your server.

Good luck.